# Table in Excel "2010" from SQL Server stored procedure with parameter field in workbook

Tags: mysql, excel, stored-procedures

This might probably be answered somewhere but I get answers for excel 2007, I need help with getting data into my spreadsheet (Excel 2010) through a stored proc.

Like this example :http://codebyjoshua.blogspot.com/2012/01/get-data-from-sql-server-stored.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aaaha ! I got it, I guess at first I did not research well.

See on this link :

https://blogs.office.com/2010/06/07/running-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-excel-no-vba/

### Steps below from the above provided link.

Step 1: Data tab – > From Other Sources -> From SQL Server
Step 2: Enter Credentials. Your server name can be an IP address
Step 3: Choose any old table or view. Pick a small one because we’ll discard it later anyway.
Step 4: Excel will pop up the Import Data dialog box. Click Properties here (NOT THE OK BUTTON).
Step 5: Click on the Definition tab. There, change Command Type to SQL, and then enter your Stored Procedure name in the Command Text input.
Step 6: Excel complains about something….blah…blah…blah. Click Yes – (as in yes I know what I’m doing).
Step 7: Excel will activate the Import Data dialog box again. This time click OK to fire the Stored Procedure and return the results.
Step 8: Marvel at your results

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos Thanks for the advice I did put the important steps from the link.